# C# Selenium Automated Log in

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to log in on a website, but every time I search for the username input I get:

> Unable to locate element

I tried by xPath, name, class.

Also when I use `driver.Title` I dont get anything.

```cs
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "***"; // cant show it, security reasons
var pageSource = driver.PageSource;
string title = driver.Title;
Console.WriteLine("Titlu: " + title);
          driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/span/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/input")).SendKeys("ciu4clj");
//also tried this
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ng-app']/div/div/div/div[2]/span/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/input")).SendKeys("ciu4clj");
```

The HTML code

```html
<input type="text" min="" max="" match-data="" placeholder="Username" title="Username" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-required="required" ng-model="textValue" ng-model-options="options || {}" ng-keydown="keydown({$event: $event})" tb-enter="modelCtrl.$commitViewValue(); onEnter({$event: $event}); triggerEnter()" ng-paste="onPaste()" tb-auto-select="autoSelect" tb-focus="focus" tabindex="0" tb-test-id="textbox-username-input" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" ng-trim="true" class="tb-text-box-input tb-enable-selection ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" name="username" required="required">
```

Comment: is `username input` inside iframe if yes switch to it before sendkeys to username input

Answer (score 1):

The xpaths you are using are overly complicated, and can be simplified a great deal. In fact, it might be easier to use CSS selectors to locate the elements:

```cs
IWebElement usernameField = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name = 'username']");

usernameField.SendKeys("ciu4clj");
```

Similarly, I bet the password field has "password" as its name:

```cs
IWebElement passwordField = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name = 'password']");

passwordField.SendKeys("...");
```

You can take this one step further and create a [Page Object](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) for the login page:

```cs
public class LoginPage
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    private IWebElement PasswordField => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name = 'password']"));
    private IWebElement UsernameField => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name = 'username']"));

    // You might need to change this XPath to "input[@type = 'submit' and contains(., 'Login')]""
    private IWebElement LoginButton => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(., 'Login')]"));

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void Login(string username, string password)
    {
        UsernameField.SendKeys(username);
        PasswordField.SendKeys(password);
        LoginButton.Click();
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```cs
var page = new LoginPage(driver);

page.Login("ciu4clj", "...");
```

Comment: I did the changes, but i still get the same error: "Unable to locate element: input[name = 'username']"

Comment: @Siespi123: Are you sure the username field is on the page when the page loads? It could be a timing issue.